# C++ loop through map while erasing

Tags: c++

To loop through a map in c++ we do sth like this

```
map<string,int> mymap;
map<string,int>::iterator it= mymap.begin();
while(it!=mymap.end()) {
   //code here
   it++;
}
```

What if in the "code here" part i have an if statement that if evaluated to true, it erases one element from the map? How should my code change so that it still loops through all **mymap** elements in order?

Comment: Remove that element and continue as you would.  It should not affect the order.

Comment: @Roman Taking care not to increment the iterator *after* you have invalidated it by erasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase :

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other
>   references and iterators are not affected.

(So make sure you increment and save a "next" iterator *before* you erase.

Edit: In fact since `C++11`, `erase` returns the next iterator anyway, so you may use that.)

Answer (score 3):

you may want to reassign your iterator when you erase an element, as it wont be valid otherwise...

```
it = mymap.erase(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid using the iterator after invalidating it when erasing, the loop body should be like this:

```
if (should_erase) {
    it = my_map.erase(it); // C++11: returns the next iterator
    my_map.erase(it++);    // Historic C++: no helpful return value
} else {
    ++it;
}
```